# "To do" or not "to do"

Tags: usability, user-expectation, wording

I need to display a small block on site which displays actions, that user may pay attention for (unread messages, unfilled profile fields, etc.).

Is it a good practice to have such blocks at all and what is the best way to name it? Currently it is named as "to do", but I think that it is a bad choice.

Answer (score 2):

I think you describe something like badges, which is supplied [in Material Design Lite (MDL)](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#badges-section) and [in Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#badges) (and probably many of the latest web frameworks).

MDL provides a definition:

> The Material Design Lite (MDL) **badge** component is an onscreen notification element. A badge consists of a small circle, typically containing a number or other characters, that appears in proximity to another object. A badge can be both a notifier that there are additional items associated with an object and an indicator of how many items there are.

I think those are becoming usual. What is usual helps a user feel at home. If the user feels at home, I think the UX design was a success.

As for the name: "to do" may be a bad choice, but it depends on what it represents.

Comment: @downvoter I have no problem being downvoted when I am doing something wrong. Please just explain, so that I know what I can do better next time.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted but it would be good if you quote the relevant part from the links. Links rot after a while.

Comment: @Mayo Done, as far as possible. Those are mainly 'How-to' documentations, with more demonstrations than explanations. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Chop, thanks, it makes sense. As for me "to do" is a bad name, cause it is associated with to-do lists and services, and those are not for notifications, of course.